# How to I change a specific range of pixels with respect to a condition given in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, imagefilter, python-imageio

Libraries Imported:

```
    %matplotlib inline
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import misc
    import imageio
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from skimage import data
```

Like I created a:

```
    low_value_filter= dogs2 < 80
```

and did:

```
     dogs2[low_value_filter]=0
```

so all the pixels in the image with pixel value less than 80 became black.
I want to add the low_value_filter just to the right half of the image(or actually a specific range of pixels) instead of the full image. Below are images of a few attempts I made.

[This is the image after adding a circular mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUDYm.png)  [Low_value_filter to whole image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afY4m.png)
[Attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrBHF.png)[Attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxOgC.png)[Attempt 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkSvI.png)

Edit:

```
     center_col= total_cols/2
```

Comment: do this: low_value_filter = np.zeros_like(dogs);   low_value_filter[upper:lower, left:right] = dogs < 80;   dogs[low_value_filter.astype(bool)] = 0

Comment: Hey, thats what i've done actually. The error i'm getting is: (boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 640 but corresponding boolean dimension is 320). Basically the shape of the image is 475,640,3 and on taking the right half (low_value_filter[upper:lower, left:right] = dogs < 80)  on this step, the shape of low_value_filter is 475,320,3.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. Here's the fix: low_value_filter = np.zeros_like(dogs); low_value_filter[upper:lower, left:right] = dogs[upper:lower, left:right] < 80; dogs[low_value_filter.astype(bool)] = 0

Comment: did you notice the line ' low_value_filter = np.zeros_like(dogs);' ? this will make 'low_value_filter' have the same shape as your image.

Comment: Hey @yannziselman. This worked. I got what you did. Thanks a lot mate!!

Comment: you're welcome, you can post a self answer if you want

Comment: Yes I will! @yannziselman

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to this problem.

*Create an array of zeros of the same shape as the image:*

`low_value_filter = np.zeros_like(dogs)`

*Select the range of the image you want to add your filter to:*

`low_value_filter[upper:lower, left:right] = dogs[upper:lower, left:right] < 80`
**(This will make the low_value_filter an array of 0's and 1's with respect to the range you've selected)**

*Now, just add the filter to your image as an index range of bool type and set it equal to whatever pixel value you want to (I've chosen 0 in this case)*

`dogs[low_value_filter.astype(bool)] = 0`